How are some FIDE rated tournaments organizing 3 classical games per day?
58th Begonia Open 2024 was a FIDE rated tournament held in March 2024 in Ballarat, Australia. The tournament consisted of 7 rounds and on one of the days there were 3 rounds of classical chess a day. 
But according to FIDE's Handbook:

1.1.3      No more than 2 rounds shall be played on any day.

How are some tournaments organizing 3 rounds a day also being FIDE-rated simultaneously? I'm sure there would be more tournaments like this organizing 3 classical games a day. Is there something more to this rule that I am missing?

3 rounds per day are quite common for weekend tournaments - especially if time control is on the shorter side (60+30 instead of 90+30). It's the only way to fit 7 round swiss into friday - saturday - sunday schedule. As Brian answered this of course means that you cannot score norms in such events.


How are some tournaments organizing 3 rounds a day also being FIDE-rated simultaneously?

The simple answer is "because it's not against the rules for FIDE rated tournaments". What you have quoted is from the FIDE Title Regulations effective from 1 January 2024. So, if a tournament is registered with FIDE for rating and there are more than two rounds in a day then it will not qualify for title norms.
FIDE publishes a separate document, FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 March 2024, covering tournaments where norms are not available. This says only,


Rate of Play

1.1     For a game to be rated each player must at the start of the game have the following minimum periods in which to complete all the moves, assuming the game lasts 60 moves.
Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating of 2400 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 120 minutes.
Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating 1800 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 90 minutes.
Where both of the players in the game are rated below 1800, each player must have a minimum of 60 minutes.

and regarding playing hours:


Hours of Play

3.1     There must be no more than 12 hours play in one day. This is calculated based on games that last 60 moves, although games played using increments may last longer.

On these grounds the Ballarat Open qualifies for FIDE rating but any title norms achieved would not be recognised. For reference here is the FIDE rating for the tournament.

So the 1.1.3 rule applies to title norms only and not to the games that determine if a player achieves the rating requirement for a title(eg: >= 2200 for CM)? I don't quite understand the point of restricting the rule only to norms but maybe that's just another question.

@AbhyudayVaish: With a few exceptions, a tournament needs to be at least 9 rounds long for a player to have a chance at a norm. See section 1.6 at https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B012024
